# Laravel | MySQL error when i run php artisan migrate command

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am about installing [Concierge - Laravel 5.x](https://packalyst.com/packages/package/timegridio/concierge)

To use it in a simple car rental booking with manual verfication and confirmation

after installing ,adding providers and publishing vendor

i get this error when i migrate database :

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error
>   or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check
>   the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version f or the
>   right syntax to use near 'after `id`, `deleted_at` timestamp null,
>   `created_at` timestamp null, `updated_a' at line 1 (SQL: create table`
>   services`(`id`int unsigned not null auto_increment p rimary key,`
>   business_id`int unsigned not null,`slug`varchar(255) not null,`
>   name`varchar(255) not null,`duration`int unsigned not null default
>   '60',`description`varchar(255) not null,`prere quisites
>   `varchar(255) null,`color`varchar(12) null,`type_id`int unsigned
>   null after`id`,`deleted_at`timestamp null,`created_at`timestamp
>   null,`updated_at` timestamp null) default character  set utf8mb4
>   collate 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci')

the migration :

```
Schema::create('services', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('business_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('business_id')->references('id')->on('businesses')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->string('slug');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->integer('duration')->unsigned()->default(60);
            $table->string('description');
            $table->string('prerequisites')->nullable();
            $table->string('color', 12)->nullable();
            $table->integer('type_id')->unsigned()->nullable()->after('id');
            $table->foreign('type_id')->references('id')->on('service_types')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->softDeletes();
            $table->Timestamps();

            $table->unique(['business_id', 'slug']);
        });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem in **after** method you calling

**after** method is for **Column Modifiers**

***Example:*** when you need to modify the table services then it will work like that.
but if you creating the table then its not necessary. you can serialize the attributes as you write it on migration file.

```
Schema::table('services', function (Blueprint $table) {
     $table->integer('type_id')->unsigned()->nullable()->after('id');
});
```

So in you code its should be like that:

```
Schema::create('services', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('type_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
            $table->integer('business_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('business_id')->references('id')->on('businesses')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->string('slug');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->integer('duration')->unsigned()->default(60);
            $table->string('description');
            $table->string('prerequisites')->nullable();
            $table->string('color', 12)->nullable();
            $table->foreign('type_id')->references('id')->on('service_types')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->softDeletes();
            $table->Timestamps();

            $table->unique(['business_id', 'slug']);
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using **vagrant**, you mush **ssh** to your VM and run the commands from there. Otherwise you WILL get permission errors every time.